# Is there a config that allows opening of files together?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, if I open `Button.jsx`, VS Code will open `Button.module.css` on another panel.

Basically side-by-side viewing of related files.

Comment: how should VSC know which files are related, maybe you have 4 related files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) v0.16.0

Use the command `htmlRelatedLinks.openFile` and create key bindings that are active based on the languageID of the current editor.

Maybe you have to change `editorLangId == javascriptreact` because I don't know the languageID of `.jsx` files

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+i r",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.module.css",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": "split"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == javascriptreact"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i r",
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": {
      "file": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension:find=\\.module:replace=:}.jsx",
      "method": "vscode.open",
      "viewColumn": "split"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == css"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it just now and it's exactly what I wanted. Though I'll still try to find a way to trigger the command on file open. But this is a good starting point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to define file "groups" in such way that opening a file will automagically open related files. What you can do to achieve opening the files side-by-side is the following, as your related files will probably be in the same location: 1. `Ctrl+click` on file explorer to select the files, then drag them to editor, then 2. click on filename then drag that to the right. This will open the files side-by-side:

[image]